# Cannot assign to this

Tags: c++

I have a class like so:

```
class Node {
    // data
    Node* next;
    void operator++(int);
};
```

And when I define the post-increment operator like so:

```
void Node::operator++(int) {
    this = this->next;
}
```

I get the error `Expression is not assignable` on `this = this->next;`.

What's up with this? How do I get `this` to point to `next`?

Comment: `this` can only be used as a pointer used to refer to the current instance. Assigning to `this` would make no sense. Why would you want to do that ?

Comment: maybe you could change to `Node* Node::operator++(int) { return this->next; }`

Comment: BTW it is rather weird for postfix `operator++` to return void. That is bound to confuse users. One would expect it to return a `Node`.

Comment: @Jichao `operator++(int)` of `Node` should return a `Node`, not a `Node*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't even try. It won't work, and if you could make it work, it would be a bad thing anyway.

From the looks of things, your node is in something like a linked list. If that's the case, then what you normally want is something like:

```
template <class T>
class linked_list { 

    class node { 
        node *next;
        T data;
    };

    node *head;
public:
    class iterator { 
        node *n;
    public:
        iterator(node *n=NULL) : n(n) {}

        iterator &operator++() { 
            n=n->next;
            return *this;
        }
        bool operator!=(iterator const &other) const { 
            return n != other.n;
        }
        // ...        
    };

    iterator begin() { return iterator(n); }
    iterator end()   { return iterator();  }
};
```

Comment: So basically use `linked_list::iterator`'s `++` operator to traverse the list instead of trying to give `linked_list::node` it's own `++` operator?

Comment: I doubt that `operator++` is correct, it should `return *this;`.

Comment: @MichaelDorst: Correct. Incrementing a node of a linked list doesn't make much sense at all. Incrementing an iterator does.

Answer (score 1):

This can not be changed. it is constant.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ standard the `this` pointer is a *prvalue* expression (see [[class.this]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.this)), however the assignment operator requires an *lvalue* as its left operand (see [[expr.ass]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass)).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. Even if by some dirty tricks you change `this`, the change won't be propagated to the caller. `this` is a hidden formal argument of methods.

Answer (score 0):

You seem very confused in terms of what you are trying to do here. You have a `node` class which represents a node in the list. Typically one would also have an `iterator` class which represents the position in the list that you are currently at. It seems to me that you are trying to use `++` to iterate to the next item in a list, but to do that you would need the iterator as a class of it's own.

In general it makes no sense to assign to the `this` pointer - `this` refers to the current object context, you can't just change that context by setting the `this` pointer.

I hope this will help you somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

You just discovered why the STL has *iterators*. An iterator is holding a pointer to a node as a member of itself or in some cases it is a pointer. It could also modify it's member variable. Maybe try something like:

```
class Iterator {
    Node* node;
public:
    Iterator(Node* n)
        : node( n )
    {}

    Iterator& operator++()
    {
        node = node->next;
        return *this;
    }

    Iterator operator++(int)
    {
        Node* current = node;
        node = node->next;
        return Iterator(current);
    }

    Node& operator*()
    {
        return *node;
    }

    const Node& operator*() const; // etc...
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense if the dereference operator returned `node->data`? (assuming `data` is the name of the member we're iterating over) or is it better to provide access to the node and not just the value?

Comment: Yes and no. That would be quite inconsistent with how all other iterators work. It might look convenient at first, but it is a bit too much "magic" and destroys the clear layering. If you turn `Node` into an internal class of your container and `Iterator` becomes part of that design, you can of course start returning a reference to the data directly. In general, I recommend you read a lot more about the containers and iterators in the STL, as the topic is too broad for a simple Q/A-style here.

Answer (score -1):

The hidden parameter 'this' is passed with the 'const' qualifier. Hence it cannot be changed.
[Hidden this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/87-the-hidden-this-pointer/)